# How can you calculate the prices with 2 decimals, not with 4 decimals?

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice, grand-total, subtotal

How can you set in Magento2 that all the **calculations** you make on orders, invoices, price rules,…, to be done with **2 decimals** not with 4 decimals?

> **Attention**, I mean the calculation of prices and not the display of
> prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the path `/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/Calculation/AbstractCalculator.php`
In the `deltaRound()` method, we need to remove the following code:

```
if ($round) {
    $roundPrice = $this->calculationTool->round($roundPrice);
}
```

Some methods by which that code can be removed:

- Class extension
- Create Plugin
- Create Patch

---

Or the permanent declaration of the `$round` parameter as `false`.

```
$round = false
```